# Hatcher exercise: If all maps $f:S^1\to X$ are nullhomotopic, then $\pi_1(X)=0$ - how do we prove this when the homotopies *don't* preserve basepoint?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, solution-verification

This exercise is seemingly very easy:

> Let $X$ be a space. Show that: $$\pi_1(X,x_0)=0$$For all $x_0\in X$ iff. all maps $f:S^1\to X$ are nullhomotopic.

The problem: Hatcher remarks at the end of the exercise:

> "In
> this problem, ‘homotopic’ means ‘homotopic without regard to basepoints’"

Which is rather problematic. In $\pi_1(X,x_0)$, the elements are equivalence classes of loops $f:I\to X$, $f(0)=x_0=f(1)$, with equivalence relation homotopy equivalences **of paths**. That is, if $[f]=[g]$ in the group then the homotopy $f\overset{\varphi}{\simeq}g$ necessarily has $\varphi(0,t)=x_0=\varphi(1,t)$ for all $t\in I$.

It is clear to me what (I think) the intended solution is:

> Let $f$ be a loop about $x_0$ in $X$. Since $f(0)=f(1)$, $f$ can be identified as a continuous function $S^1\to X$. By assumption there is a homotopy $f\simeq C_{x}$ for some $x\in X$. Therefore the loop $f$ is nullhomotopic so $[f]$ is the identity in $\pi_1(X,x_0)$. As $f$ was arbitrary, $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ is trivial.

The problem is that this homotopy might not be a homotopy of paths, so $[f]=[C_{x_0}]$ might not - necessarily - hold. There is also, I'm pretty sure, nothing further we can conclude along the lines of: If such homotopies always exist, homotopies of paths must also always exist. So I think, as written, the exercise is wrong.

Is this an oversight, or have I misinterpreted what Hatcher was referring to? For context, this is the full exercise:

> Let $X$ be a space. Show that all three are equivalent:
>
> 1. All maps $f:S^1\to X$ are nullhomotopic
> 2. All maps $f:S^1\to X$ can be extended to maps $f:D^2\to X$.
> 3. $\pi_1(X,x_0)=0$ for all $x_0\in X$.

Now, I am sure that Hatcher was right to remark that we need to not assume homotopies preserve endpoints in $(1)\iff(2)$, since in fact (my solution for) $(2)\implies(1)$ doesn't guarantee a homotopy of paths. So perhaps he meant the remark for $(1)$ and $(2)$ but did not intend for it to apply to $(3)$, but that wouldn't really make sense. What's going on?

Comment: The exercise is correct. You can show that if $X$ is path-connected then the set of homotopy classes of maps $S^1 \to X$, ignoring basepoints, can be identified with the set of conjugacy classes of $\pi_1$ (with respect to any basepoint), which is trivial iff $\pi_1$ is trivial.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Right (that's the next exercise, actually!). Hatcher doesn't suppose $X$ is path-connected in this exercise though, sadly

Comment: Lack of path-connectedness is not a big deal: show that for each $x_0 \in X$, the statement is true in the path component containing $x_0$.